# Newline separated JSON instead of comma separated

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am getting some data from an API, that I want to then import into a BigQuery table. The doc specifies :

```
JSON data must be newline delimited. Each JSON object must be on a separate line in the file.
```

And I cannot seem to find a way to convert my JSON.

Here is my code, getting the first 2 lines of the API response and printing them :

```py
    cols = ["id","email","surname"]

    for line in response.text.split("\n")[1:3]:
        obj={}
        for name,value in zip(cols,line.split(";")):
            obj[name] = value
        data.append(obj)

    print(json.dumps(data))
```

The output is the following :

```
[{"id": "1", "email": "randommail@provider.fr", "surname": "Alice"}, {"id": "2", "email": "randommail@gmail.com", "surname": "Bob"}]
```

How should I proceed to format the JSON like this ?

```
{"id": "1", "email": "randommail@provider.fr", "surname": "Alice"}
{"id": "2", "email": "randommail@gmail.com", "surname": "Bob"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an answer since comments are limited regarding formatting. Like you wrote, you should handle each dictionary as a separated json:

```
output = ''
cols = ["id","email","surname"]
    for line in response.text.split("\n")[1:3]:
        obj={}
        for name,value in zip(cols,line.split(";")):
            obj[name] = value
        output += json.dumps(obj) + '\n'
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I found another way of doing it but I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is the following :

```py
cols = ["id","email","surname"]
for line in response.text.split("\n")[1:3]:
    obj={}
    for name,value in zip(cols,line.split(";")):
        obj[name] = value
    data.append(obj)

myString = "\n".join([json.dumps(row) for row in data])
```